# Rotate a word in Python with a key

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

> Write a function called `rotate_word()` that takes a string and an integer as parameters, and returns a new string that contains the letters from the original string rotated by the given amount. `Rotate_word('cheer',7) == 'jolly'`, `Rotate_word('melon', -10) = 'cubed'`,**

My Python code is:

```
def Rotate_word(str_, num_):
    result = ''
    for i in str_:
        i = chr(ord(i) + num_)
        result = result + i
    return (result)

str_ =input("Enter a string: ")
num_ = int(input("Enter rotate number: "))
print (Rotate_word(str_,num_))
```

It gives output like:

```
Enter a string: cheer  
Enter rotate number: 7  
jolly
```

Which is correct.

```
Enter a string: melon  
Enter rotate number: -10  
c[bed
```

This is wrong the correct answer is `cubed`

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to "wrap around" when going below `'a'` or above `'z'`.

However instead of using `chr` and `ord` you can simply using `str.translate` with `str.maketrans`:

```
import string

def Rotate_word(str_, num_):
    # Create a translation table from lowercase characters to shifted lowercase chars
    tab = str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, 
                        string.ascii_lowercase[num_:] + string.ascii_lowercase[:num_])
    return str_.translate(tab)

str_ =input("Enter a string: ")
num_ = int(input("Enter rotate number: "))
print(Rotate_word(str_,num_))
```

It would need a bit of additional work to make it also handle uppercase letters. But it produces the correct output for `'melon'` and `-10` and `'cheer'` and `7`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only need lowercase characters, you need to wrap it around if it "overflows", which means if it goes beyond `z` or before `a`:

```
left_bound = ord("a")
right_bound = ord("z")
```

and then do something like this:

```
char_num = ord(i) + num_
while char_num > right_bound: char_num -= 26
while char_num < left_bound: char_num += 26
i = chr(char_num)
result = result + i
```

There are shorter and more elegant solutions, but this is the most straight forward fix

Answer (score 1):

```
s=input()
n=int(input())
s2=""
for l in s:
    s2=s2+chr(ord(l)+n)
print(s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_ ='melon'
num_ = -10
cstr=''
for i in str_:
  t= (ord(i) + num_)
  if t<97:
    t=123-(97-t)
  cstr =cstr + chr(t)
print(cstr)

output is cubed
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?